# Passing in types properly to Redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, reducers

I'm having a bit of difficulty trying to pass a proper type to my action property in my reducer function in Redux with Typescript. In regular es6 syntax I would pass in a type like so:

```
action: {}
```

But in Typescript is acting for a more specific action type so I've tried something like this:

```
import {
  UPDATE_STATE,
} from '../constants/ActionTypes';

import * as Actions from '../actions/index.js';

const initialState = {
  someState: '',
}

// TODO: Type checking here is throwing an error

export default function counter(state = initialState, action : Actions ) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case UPDATE_STATE:
      return {
        ...state,
      }
    }
}
```

Typescript is currently throwing this error when I try and compile in Webpack:

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/reducers/numberpad.tsx:27:64 
>       TS2304: Cannot find name 'Actions'.

Actions:

```
index.js
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes'

export function update(val) {
  return { type: types.UPDATE, val }
}
```

Constants:

```
export const UPDATE = 'UPDATE'
```

So far I'm at a loss, I've also tried passing in a type as "object" (as what gets returned from my actions is an actual object) but, this does not seem to get recognized either. I've also tried specifying a type of "any" to let this be more flexible, but TS does not seem to like that either.

I'm a little bit confused as to what TS is checking for in these instances. Any thoughts would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please show your actions/index file where are are exporting your actions? My guess is the issue is there

Comment: Just added them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action should be an interface or type.

Your import is importing everything from the index.js file and naming it as "Actions".

In your index.js file, you need to declare a type or interface e.g.

```
export interface IAction {
    type: string;
    data: any;
}
```

Then in your reducer, you need:

```
import {IAction} from '../actions/index.js';
```

...and then your reducer:

```
export default function counter(state = initialState, action : IAction) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case UPDATE_STATE:
      return {
        ...state,
      }
    }
}
```